# Laravel: Difference between validated() and safe()->all()

Tags: laravel

What is the difference between the two methods `validated()` and `safe()->all()`?

Comment: https://www.magutti.com/blog/refactor-form-request-with-request-safe

refer this it may give you some idea

Comment: Try it and find out for yourself, please. In addition, read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#form-request-validation).